# Why can't I setup my exchange account on my home computer?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, remote-access, exchange-2003

My work exchange has very little security, I can add it to any smart phone, access it via the web but I cannot add it to my home outlook 2010. It doesnt make any sense to me that my iPhone/Android/Windows Phone 7 can connect but my Outlook 2010 cannot.

The information I provide to the phones is simple

Server: mail.domain.com
User: user@domain.com
Password: 1234

But when I try to setup the connection in Outlook it doesn't take.

Comment: Are you setting it up as an IMAP account or POP3? These things matter. Exchange uses a form of IMAP.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't take it"? What's the error message you receive?

Comment: I'm trying to set it up as Exchange over HTTP